# Drush modifying variable on settings.php

Tags: drush

Can I modify a variable of the setting php via drush?
I actually want to change

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
```

to

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on a web server then you can download [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) (for windows) or [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Then login as *root* and go to the folder that contains `settings.php`

For Putty:

> Simply nano 'filename'. That is: `nano settings.php`

This will open your file and you can make changes as you like.

With WinSCP:

> Folder structure opens up in a GUI . You can simply click and edit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Drush cannot edit the settings.php file.  You could do the above with sed.  Let me know if you want the regex to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough Rep to comment on the second response here, but the best answer to the question

> Can I modify a variable of the setting php via drush?

is:

Drush cannot modify settings.php variables.